# Update de Date e Time para verificar se está online

Tags: android

No meu app android tenho um serviço que envia de tempos em tempos uma localização do usuário e salva em outro campo lastUpdate o dia e horário em que aconteceu o update. 
Atualmente uso `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` para pegar o Date e enviar para o banco, porém o que percebo é que a hora de muitos às vezes está mais adiantada do que a hora corrente, o que fazer para padronizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tudo funcione como tu pretendes, o dispositivo que recebe a data tem de estar sincronizado com a máquina onde está o servidor. Não há como dar a volta a esta situação.

O `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` depende da data/hora do dispositivo android.

No entanto se já efectuas-te algum tipo de sincronização e o erro acontece a uma escala reduzida aconselho-te a usar o `System.currentTimeMillis();` para efetuares as comparações.